# Get row clicked in Datatables.net grid after modal closes

Tags: jquery, datatables, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Datatables.net to display a table of payments.

In each row, the last column contains an Edit button.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCategoryTypeEditor" data-action="@Url.Action("EditCategory", new { @item.PaymentId })">Edit</button>
```

The button contains a data-action attribute with a link pointing to an Action.

The Edit button launches a modal window which uses the jQuery Load function to call the Action of the button to retrieve the contents of the modal body.

```
$('#modalCategoryTypeEditor').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var toggleModal = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
    var actionUrl = toggleModal.data('action') // Extract info from data-* attributes

    $(this).find('.modal-body').load(actionUrl);
});
```

Once the user clicks the Save button of the modal window, an Action is called on the server which returns a string result.

**Question**: How do I set this string result to one of the columns of the row that was clicked? In other words, at this point after the modal is closed, how do I at this point find out which row was clicked on?

I know how to detect the row that was clicked -- I'm using the below. But it's not working after the modal window is closed. Even if I encapsulate this in the 'hide.bs.modal' event.

```
$('#payments_list tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
     console.log(table.cell(table.row(this).data()));
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

---

To clarify, I know how to obtain the ID of the record belonging to the row that was clicked. I then launch my modal window where I make changes, and send the changes to the server to be saved. The server returns a string response, and I need to use this string to populate a cell in the row that was clicked. The problem is that the server response happens much later after the row click event. In other words, the function that handles the row click event launches the modal, and that's it, the function ends.

```
$('#exampleTable tbody').on( 'click', 'a', function () {
    var data = '';
    data = exampleTable.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
    console.log(data);
    var carId= data['id'];

    $('#exampleModal').modal();
})

// function that gets called after ajax form post completes
var onCompleted = function() {
    // How do I find out which row was clicked at this point
}

// form inside modal
<form id="formInsideModal" method="post" data-ajax-complete="onCompleted" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" >
    // some input fields to be saved
    <button type="submit" id="saveBtnInsideModal">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Tell me one thing, all the edit buttons have different value for their data-action attribute?

Comment: @AbdulrehmanSheikh yes.

Comment: Do you need to find the Row Index?

Answer (score 0):

Hi on your dataTable declaration put a default content column like this:

```
 "columns": [
                   {"data": "id"},
                   {"data": "fullname"},
                   {"data": "address"},
                   {"data": "company"},
                   {"data": "Cars"},
                   {
                className: "center",
                defaultContent:"<a name='idClient' class='btn btn-info' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt'></span> Show Cars Info</a>"
              }
               ]
```

and the event you should do it like this :

```
    // The click event to get the data into a new DataTable inside the modal
             //note: you have to declare the dataTable like this
             //exampleTable = $('#exampleTable').DataTable({ your stuff });
               $('#exampleTable tbody').on( 'click', 'a', function () {
                  var data = '';
                  data = exampleTable.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
                  console.log(data);
                  var carId= data['id'];
                  console.log(carId);
})
```

Hope it Helps

Comment: Updated post to clarify my question.

Answer (score 0):

The way I am interpreting your request is that you launch the Modal, Make the changes, and Submit the value to server via `$.ajax` call subsequently the server returns a string value which needs to set in a particular column of the `datatable`.

Firstly, I will have an attribute set in the Modal as `data-rowindex` as (This is a sample modal I had created; You can change it for your own):

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" id="YourModal" data-rowindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Amend</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-position" class="control-label">Position:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-position">
          </div>
        </form>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="YourModalSubmitButton" data-rowindex="-1" data-comment="" data-context="" data-tag="">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Once the Edit button is click, you need to identify the index of the row.

```
table.on("click", "tr", function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row(tr);
    var idx = row.index();

    //Set the row index to the Modal's data attribute
    $('#YourModal').data('rowindex', idx);

  });
```

You can check here whether the Index Value has been applied:

```
$('#YourModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
    var rIdx = $(this).data('rowindex');

    var modal = $(this);
//I set the rowindex value back to a data attribute in the submit button of the modal
    modal.find('#YourModalSubmitButton').data('request', rIdx);
    modal.find('.modal-title').html('The Row You Selected is ' + rIdx);
  });
```

Then On your Modal's On Submit Button Click do this:

```
$('#YourModal').find('#YourModalSubmitButton').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(event.target); // Button that triggered the modal
    var idx= target.data('rowindex');
    //To get value from Form elements
    var formElementVal = $('#YourModal').find('#Form-element-value').val();


//do your ajax call here get the result
    table.cell({
      row: idx,
      column: 1
    }).data(formElementVal).draw();
  });
```

Hope this helps.

[You can also check a JsFiddle I did for a more similar requirement.](https://jsfiddle.net/hifni/3dsq0pk2/84/)